# Detect if IPv6 is supported, OS-agnostic, no external program?

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ipv6

Is there a way to detect if IPv6 is supported on a system, without using external programs *and* in an OS-agnostic way?

I've searched high and low, here and throughout the Internet, it seems nearly every offered solution relies either on accessing `/proc` (not available on Windows & MacOS) or running external programs.

The best I can come up with is:

```py
import errno
import socket

def has_ip6():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("::1", 0))
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EADDRNOTAVAIL:
            return False
        if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED;
            return True
        raise
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "IPv6 supported"? Just that one can use IPv6 with sockets or that the system has actual IPv6 connectivity to systems on the local network or that the system has even IPv6 connectivity to the internet?

Comment: …or that the system will work on a single stack IPv6 connection (which has some additional requirements like DNS over IPv6)?

Comment: Just that I can bind to IPv6. Don't really care about connectivity to other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @averresen's answer is not correct, it did lead me to the correct answer as specified in https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/611#issuecomment-100954017 :

```py
def _is_ipv6_enabled():
    """Check whether IPv6 is enabled on this host."""
    if socket.has_ipv6:
        sock = None
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.bind((HOSTv6, 0))
            return True
        except OSError:
            pass
        finally:
            if sock:
                sock.close()
    return False
```

So basically what I did was already on the right path, I just have to add a defensive `if not socket.has_ipv6: return False` at the beginning.

---

#### Edit 1:

This is what I finally ended up with:

```py
import socket
import errno

# On Windows, the E* constants will use the WSAE* values
# So no need to hardcode an opaque integer in the sets.
_ADDR_NOT_AVAIL = {errno.EADDRNOTAVAIL, errno.EAFNOSUPPORT}
_ADDR_IN_USE = {errno.EADDRINUSE}

def system_has_ipv6() -> bool:
    if not socket.has_ipv6:
        # If the socket library has no support for IPv6, then the
        # question is moot as we can't use IPv6 anyways.
        return False
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.bind(("::1", 0))
        return True
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno in _ADDR_NOT_AVAIL:
            return False
        if e.errno in _ADDR_IN_USE:
            # This point shouldn't ever be reached. But just in case...
            return True
        # Other errors should be inspected
        raise
```

---

#### Edit 2:

I added `errno.EAFNOSUPPORT` to the `_ADDR_NOT_AVAIL` set. `EADDRNOTAVAIL` is the errno if IPv6 modules/drivers are loaded but disabled, `EAFNOSUPPORT` is the errno if IPv6 modules/drivers are not loaded at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly for cases like WSL2 which doesn't have real IPv6 support - you can't use it to connect to any external addresses or even IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses - but it does succeed in binding to ::1 or its own link-local IPv6 interface address.

Any idea how to cover that scenario?

Comment: @RReverser Not sure how. My need, as I explained in a comment in my original question, was just to detect if IPv6 is available or not, regardless of whether it is usable or not... maybe you can try opening a connection to a reachable IPv6 address?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Do not use `socket.has_ipv6`; check out @pepoluan's own answer instead!**

The socket module contains the constant [socket.has_ipv6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.has_ipv6) specifically for indicating whether or not IPv6 is supported.

Comment: Oooh, thanks! Somehow I missed that, even though I've gone up and down that page!

Comment: Wait, after some reading, I found this: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/611 ... so apparently `socket.has_ipv6` only tells you if the Python you're using support IPv6 or not, and not actually tells you about the _system's_ support for IPv6. Sorry, I have to unmark your answer attempt.

Comment: That's fair. I'll edit my answer to highlight that your own answer is correct.